# UIView element not updating

Tags: multithreading, swift, asynchronous, uiview

I need to get data from a API I’ve used debug prinln’s and these print almost instantly including the information gotten from the API, but when I try to display this info to the user in the ViewController this takes around 30 seconds to display.

I will get the information from the API here

```
func httpGet(request: NSURLRequest!, callback: (NSData?, String?) -> Void) {
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            callback(nil, error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            callback(data, nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I invoke the request and return a string for debugging

```
func loadSchedule() {
    httpGet(request) {
        (data, error) -> Void in
        onComplete(“Milo Cesar”)
}
```

And here I will display the data to the user

```
@IBAction func settingsButtonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("Settings Button Pressed: Invoking Schedule")
    Schedule().loadSchedule(){
        (scheduleData) in
        println("Found Schedule: Setting Title to \(scheduleData)")
            self.settingsButton.setTitle(scheduleData, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

The whole process from the “Settings Button Pressed: Invoking Schedule” statement in my console till I get “Found Schedule: Settings Title to Milo Cesar” takes less than a second.
Since the name already gets displayed in that console log I think that the information has been loaded. Though it takes up to 35 seconds for the Button to change it’s title.

Why does it take so long for my UIButton to update it’s title after the data has been retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are updating its title in main thread? try to wrap it up in GCD

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.settingsButton.setTitle(scheduleData, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

#### EDIT

it fixes it because everything UI related must be performed by main thread, its a restriction that comes directly from Apple. You can use background threads for long taking tasks(download data, perform long taking calculations or sort large arrays) but everything that needs to be displayed on your screen must be performed by main thread(tableview reload, animations, inserting text into label).

Also here is a great tutorial on GCD and its functionality: http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Comment: I’ve recently tried to search for literature regarding multithreading in swift but was unable to find anything particularly helpful, could you please update your answer and explain why this fixes my problem if you are able to?